# tmux ctrl-a stopped working after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, tmux, gnome-terminal

I have had my tmux prefix set to `c-a` for as long as I can remember. Immediately after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, ctrl-a no longer works. My terminal (gnome and xterm) simply display `^A`. If I change the prefix to `c-b` it works, but I really need it to work with `c-a` as that's where my muscle memory is.

Comment: To indicate the problem is solved, [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). There is no need to abuse the title.

Comment: in 2 days when SX allows me to accept my answer, I will.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer was tmux

Ubuntu 20.04 upgrades tmux to 3.0a. This has a number of breaking changes. In my case `bind -tvi-copy C-Up scroll-up` becomes `bind -Tcopy-mode C-Up send -X scroll-up` as documented here https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES

The fact that there is an error in my .tmux.conf seems to prevent the whole file from being obeyed, thus even though my .tmux.conf was setting `c-a`, tmux was ignoring this and retaining the default `c-b`.